# Start hosting with firebase

Tags: web-hosting, html, javascript, firebase

I made a new firebase project and web app, and i want to use firebase hosting on it. I have a directory set up on replit with html, js, css, but how do i host it on firebase?

I have tried looking at the docs, the cli, but one page tells me to use node.js while another tells me to use an html project. How do I host my project on firebase?

I am looking to host a static website with html and js

I am using replit to host and already have the files ready.

Comment: [This](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting) is the Firebase guide you will want to follow to host your site. The [quick start guide here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/quickstart) may also be helpful. The product you'll want to use is Firebase Hosting - Firebase has a bunch of other related offerings, so you'll want to make sure you don't get tied up in the documentation for them. [This tutorial on Medium](https://medium.com/@aleemuddin13/how-to-host-static-website-on-firebase-hosting-for-free-9de8917bebf2) looks like it may also be helpful.